# Exception handling of suspendCoroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Suspend Coroutine is used for handling callbacks in a synchronus way, but I am confused with usage of ***continuation.resumeWithException***.

According to docs it says *Resumes the execution of the corresponding coroutine so that the exception is re-thrown right after the last suspension point.*

Lets say I have a method to get FCM token

```
private suspend fun getFirebaseToken(): String? {
    return suspendCoroutine {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
            .addOnCanceledListener { it.resume(null) }
            .addOnFailureListener { exc -> it.resumeWithException(exc) }
            .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<String> ->
                if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                    it.resumeWithException(task.exception!!)
                }
                it.resume(task.result)
            }
    }
}
```

and this method is being called as

```
val firebaseToken = try {
            getFirebaseToken()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            null
        }
```

So whenever exception is thrown I am catching it which is the desired behaviour.

Lets say instead of

```
it.resumeWithException(exc)
```

I replace it with

```
throw IOException("TEST")
```

then also its coming in the catch block, hence I am not able to understand when should we use `resumeWithException` and It will be a great help if some can give a practical usage also

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tested out and saw if I write `it.resumeWithException` then my entire code till the end of the block will be read and then the exception will be thrown but if I write `throw IOException("TEST")` then the rest of the block of code is unreachable and exception will be thrown at that point itself.

Comment: I wonder what is the point of `resumeWithException` then. Why would you want to continue running the code after this? Why not always throw?

Maybe `resumeWithException` has added benefits? For instance, sometimes I have noticed that some exceptions are not bubbled to the parent and jobs continue.